# Correct Permissions, unable to move file

Tags: server, samba

Running Samba4 on Ubuntu 19.04.  Attempting to copy this file:

`-rwxrwxrwx+  1 root company  49K Jul 15 10:00 FileToMove.DOCX`

to this folder:

`drwxrwsrwx+  2 root company 4.0K Jul 12 13:52 TargetFolder`

Regardless of the OS, attempting to make this copy gives me a permission deined error. I do not see where the problem is. The `Target Folder` is
located in the following share:

`[Client-Billing]
    path= /server/Client-Billing/
    writeable = yes
    guest ok = no
    valid users = @company
    force group = company`

The Globals Section looks like this:

`[global]
   workgroup = PREMPROVSOL
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 10.0.10.0/24
   bind interfaces only = yes
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   unix charset = UTF-8
   dos charset = CP932
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 2777
   force create mode = 0777
   force directory mode = 2777`

Any Suggestions?

***EDIT ***
getfacl on the folder returns the following results:

```
Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: server/Client-Billing/TargetFolder
# owner: theuser
# group: company
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
user:root:rwx
user:777:rwx
user:3000042:rwx
group::r-x
group:root:r-x
group:3000042:rwx
mask::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:user:root:rwx
default:user:777:rwx
default:user:3000042:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:root:r-x
default:group:3000042:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

The UID and GID look odd to me.  Where are these numbers coming from?

Comment: well the owner is listed as `root` are you using sudo? what is the exact `mv`  command you are typing?

Comment: @tatsu, the owner on all my shares is root.  If the users is a member of the group then they should have appropriate access to the folder - or do I not have that correct?  The other shares work perfectly.

Comment: @tatsu `cp FileToMove.DOCX ./TargetFolder`.  Not using SU becuase I am logged in as a samba user with the correct permissions.

Comment: And what are the extended permissions of TargetFolder on the server? Run the following - without quotes - to find out: "getfacl /server/Client-Billing/TargetFolder"

Comment: @Morbius, I just edited the question.  Thanks for looking.